# Sharing URL's from Wordpress with Open Graph on Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, share

When the URL's from my site diipad.com are copied and paste or shared directly from my site, facebook doesn't process the URL and it only display the same URL i mean the excerpt and thumbnail doesn't appear.

but if i paste the same link on http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug it doesn't show any error and it does process the URL's ive checked my HTML structure and it's Ok, the metadata is the one included on the facebook wordpress plugin Open Graph.

Plaese i need help sorry for my bad english.

[HERE AN IMAGE OF THE ERROR](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-e-RgccR-bBM/UV2mByCTViI/AAAAAAAAEhM/mHsY_0SQUy4/s526/Captura%2520de%2520pantalla%2520de%25202013-04-02%252013%253A23%253A48.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just because the FB debugger doesn't complain about your HTML code, doesn't mean it's all there (it doesn't raise errors for missing tags).

There are many Open Graph plugins for WordPress (just search for "Open Graph" on wordpress.org to see). You might want to give this one a try: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-facebook/

js.

Comment: It doesn't work i try that one and i been using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/ and my links still not working on Facebook :(